# Python sklearn PCA keep lowest variance vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, variance

I want to use the sklearn pca function to keep the N vectors with the lowest variance rather than highest. I tried to implement this in numpy but it was much slower than sklearns regular PCA. Is it possible ot achieve this with sklearn pca?

Comment: Please add some code. thx

Comment: Why would you want this? It’s the core of PCA, i.e. finding directions in space (principal components) along which projections have the largest variance.